# MySql User access update procedure

Tags: mysql

I would like to make a procedure to update a table that stores my user details including there IP addresses. It also needs to update the user access table something like below.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `UpDateIPAddr`(IN K int(11), IN `V`varchar(16))
BEGIN                      
  RENAME USER (select UName from Employee where TKey = K)@(select IPAddr from Employee where TKey = K) TO (select UName from Employee where TKey = K)@V;
  UPDATE timecard.Settings SET `IPAddr`= V WHERE `TKey`= K;
END
```

How can I do this

Comment: You want a _stored procedure_ or _trigger_? Difference being the trigger will fire on insert/update of a particular table.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assemble the `rename user` statement in a string format and execute it with a [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) because you cannot use subqueries directly within the rename user statement.

Use [select ... into ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) statement to assign data from tables to variables.